# Как поместить данный JSON в room sql

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-room, room

**Вот сам JSON**

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "sucsses": true,
  "data": {
   "booking_info": [
  {
    "_id": "5aca5b780f8fe503bca4c535",
    "imageBooking": [

    ],
    "nameBooking": "Название заявки",
    "descriptionBooking": "Описание заявки",
    "taskBooking": "Подробное описание заявки",
    "priceBooking": "2500",
    "rateBooking": null,
    "coordinateBooking": {
      "latitudeBooking": 43.4534366,
      "longitudeBooking": 43.4534366
    },
    "clockWork": null,
    "user_id": "5ac7d0d133379a10bc527861"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ace309c78763c1b2c99388a",
    "imageBooking": [

    ],
    "nameBooking": "Название заявки",
    "descriptionBooking": "Описание заявки",
    "taskBooking": "Подробное описание заявки",
    "priceBooking": "2500",
    "rateBooking": null,
    "coordinateBooking": {
      "latitudeBooking": 43.4534366,
      "longitudeBooking": 43.4534366
    },
    "clockWork": null,
    "user_id": "5ac7d0d133379a10bc527861"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5ace320a78763c1b2c99388b",
    "imageBooking": [

    ],
    "nameBooking": "Название заявки",
    "descriptionBooking": "Описание заявки",
    "taskBooking": "Подробное описание заявки",
    "priceBooking": "2500",
    "rateBooking": null,
    "coordinateBooking": {
      "latitudeBooking": 43.4534366,
      "longitudeBooking": 43.4534366
    },
    "clockWork": null,
    "user_id": "5ac7d0d133379a10bc527861"
  }
]
  }
}
```

**Вот дата класс**

```
data class BookingModel(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int,
    var code: Int,
    var sucsses: Boolean
    var data: BookingModel?,
    var booking_info: List<BookingModel>?,
    var nameBooking: String,
    var descriptionBooking: String,
    var priceBooking: String
)



@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertBooking(user: BookingModel)
```

Comment: вы хотите сохранить JSON в базе (как String)?

Comment: Не смотрите как я получаю строку  с сервера при помощи ретрофит BookingModel.data.booking_info.nameBooking, вот мне таким же образом нужно получить , только уже при помощи room

Comment: Вопрос был как записать в Room теперь Вы говорите что надо достать из Room. Сформулируйте нормально вопрос, из вышесказанного непонятно что Вам надо реализовать.

Comment: Для начала, как вы достаёте данные из тела response от Ретрофита? У вас по приведённому коду структура JSON и модель отличаются. Судя по `json`, у вас `data` - это `json object`, который содержит элемент-массив `booking_info`. И по описанному дата-классу `BookingModel` никак не сериализуется в приведённый вами json. Да и к тому же, почему в `BookingModel` поле `data` является тоже `BookingModel`? А `booking_info` - вообще массив тех же самых `BookingModel`.

Comment: Да json не много отличается, ну это не суть, вот смотрите достаю я данные  BookingModel.data.booking_info.nameBooking вот таким образом

Comment: Ваш data class не соответствует структуре JSON, разберитесь со структурами данных и все станет яснее.

Comment: В каком смысле не соответствует?  Я вытаскиваю данные с помощью данного дата класса, но  не все так как нет надобности  , тут вопрос задан не какая структуру моего дата класса, а как мне поместить данных в room)))

Answer (score 1):

Room может сохранять объекты в базу. По сути он перед сохранение, преобразует объект в JSON и при запросе наоборот, из JSON'a в объект. Достаточно просто указать как класс объекта в который надо преобразовывать.

В основном классе ROOM прописываете:

```
@Database(entities = {Data.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(Data.class) // <---- Это главная строчка в этом классе
public abstract class MyDataBase extends RoomDatabase {

public abstract DataDao getDataDao();
```

}

Дальше в Entity указываете

```
@Entity(tableName = "data")

@TypeConverter
fun toJSON(data: Data): String {
    return Gson().toJson(data)
}

@TypeConverter
fun fromJSON(str: String): Data {
    return Gson().fromJson(str, Data::class.java)
}
```

Comment: Не помогает это решение, я уже пробовал использовать typeconverter-ы

Comment: "не помогает" - в чем проблема?

Comment: чтобы достать список BookingModel.data.booking_info.nameBooking так что тут typeconverter не вариант, да и он не работает, я уже пробовал использовать type converter